# Use variable in excel IF ELSE formula

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, formula

I have something like this in pandas dataframe:

```
flag_N = 0
if((df1["DMD"] == 0) & (flag_N == 0)):
     df1["AVL"] = 0
else:
     df1["AVL"] = N_Sup - df1["DMD"]
     flag_N = 1
N_Sup = N_Sup - df1["DMD"]
```

Above script is in loop, so flag_N and N_Sup values are getting changed on each iteration. Now I want to embed this logic as formula in excel using macro. However, I am not finding any way to assign variables inside if or else statement. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to adjust the question's tags; perhaps add panda, remove excel-formula (which refers to a worksheet formula)?  Also have you looked for similar existing questions/answers?  This seems like something that would have had multiple similar answers already.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply missed a double quote:

```
else:
     df1["AVL] = N_Sup - df1["DMD"]
```

Should be:

```
else:
     df1["AVL"] = N_Sup - df1["DMD"]
             ^
here it is:--+
```

Comment: Thanks. This was a typo as I didn't copy paste whole code and adapted it to make it simpler. Pandas script is working fine but I need corresponding code as excel formula.